# How to use custom data type constructors correctly?

Tags: haskell

I wrote my data type:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a Color (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

And I want to use it, but I don't understand how. By design I want to create a function that returns an empty tree (tree with `Leaf`), but I don't understand what I should pass to the constructor, I tried something like this:

```
emptyTree:: Tree a
emptyTree = Tree
```

I also get the following warning

```
Data constructor not in scope: Tree :: t0 -> Tree a • Perhaps you meant ‘True’
```

P.S

I have already imported the module with the tree type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *type constructor* is `Tree`, that is to construct a *type*, not data. The *data constructor(s)* here are `Leaf` and `Node`, these are thus used to construct objects. Type constructors and data constructors *can* have the same name, but since the "type world" and the "value world" do not (really) interact, that does not create confusion for the compiler.

Here you thus can use `Leaf` or `Node`. Here `Leaf` is the only sensical thing, so:

```
emptyTree:: Tree a
emptyTree = Leaf
```

But you can use `Leaf` anywhere in the code, so defining this is *not* necessary.

Comment: Is there any problem if I pass the result of this function to a function that expects a tree?

Comment: `Data constructor not in scope: Leaf :: Tree a | 8 | emptyTree = Leaf | ^^^^`


And I also get this ;(

Comment: @student422: are you sure you are not using a different `Tree` type, like from the `Data.Tree` module https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Graph.html#t:Tree

Comment: @student422: you can both use `emptyTree` and `Leaf` to any part in the expression that expects a value of type `Tree a`.